# `&` in function parameter list

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I saw this in some code and I'm confused about one thing:

```
struct mystrct {...};
typedef mystrct* ptr_mystrct;

void fun1(ptr_mystrct &val)
{...}
void fun2(ptr_mystrct val)
{...}

main()
{
  mystrct foo;
  ptr_mystrct ptr_foo = &foo;
  fun1(ptr_foo);
  fun2(&foo); //this works fine
  fun1(&foo); //this is NOT valid (compiler error)
}
```

What is the purpose of `&` before `val`? At first I thought it will take the address to the pointer (`val` will point to `ptr_foo` location) but it apparently doesn't.

Also, why does `fun2(&foo)` compile where `fun1(&foo)` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It declares the parameter as a reference. The parameter becomes in/out rather than C++/C's normal in only.

This updates the structure passed to the function.

```
 void fun1 (ptr_mystruct &val)
 {
    val = somevalue ;
 }
```

This updates a copy of the parameter in fun2 so the caller never sees the change.

```
 void fun2 (ptr_mystruct val)
 {
    val = somevalue ;
 }
```

Here fun2 expects a pointer a pointer to a structure. Works

> ```
> fun2(&foo); //this works fine
> ```

Here fun1 expects a pointer to a structure and you are passing a pointer to a pointer:

> ```
> fun1(&foo); //this is NOT valid (compiler error)
> ```

IMHO, this example has one level of indirection more than needed for fun1. This is what you really need for a structure passed by reference:

```
void fun1(mystrct &val)
```

This is what you'd do in the olde days of C before references to make a structure read/write

```
void fun2(ptr_mystrct val)
```

Comment: Tidy up the use of brackets and braces

Comment: "Here fun1 expects a pointer to a structure and you are passing a pointer to a pointer" Neither of those parts are true.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping the `typedef`s, we have:

```
void fun1(mystrct*& val);

fun1(&foo);
```

`fun1` takes an lvalue reference to a pointer to `mystrct`. `&foo` is indeed a pointer to `mystrct`, but it's an rvalue (specifically a prvalue), not an lvalue, so the types mismatch. You can think of it as `&foo` is a temporary value, and you can't take an non-const lvalue reference to a temporary.

This is the equivalent error to trying to do something like:

```
void fun(int& );
fun(1);
```

`fun2` just takes a pointer - not a reference - so `fun2(&foo)` is totally fine.